# Show hourly clicks of a mysqli query for one day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, mysqli

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors_table` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`visitor_ip` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
`visitor_browser` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`visitor_hour` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_minute` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00',
`visitor_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`visitor_day` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
`visitor_month` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
`visitor_year` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL,
`visitor_page` VARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

The following query gets the visitors per day:

```
"SELECT visitor_date FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_date = CURDATE()";
```

Now I want output the data hourly. See this example:

```
Day     Year Hours     Clicks
July 4, 2011 00:00:00  4
July 4, 2011 01:00:00  12 
July 4, 2011 02:00:00  75
July 4, 2011 03:00:00  27
```

and so on...

Could someone help me? I can't get clear with the output of the total visitors by hours for one day!

With the following query comes only this result:

```
SELECT visitor_date, count(*) FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_date = CURDATE() GROUP BY visitor_hour

visitor_date count(*) 
2013-08-31   4
2013-08-31   7
```

I need to get the results by hours like written as above!
Where is my mistake or how can i show it with php?

Comment: Have you even tried anything apart from sorting out your query and database table?

Comment: don't you just need to expand on what you already have with date, to search by where hour is whatever (ie get what hour it is now and anything within that hour display?)

Comment: why are you storing all those time values as seperate fields? it'd be far more efficient to use a single datetime field. it will also DRASTICALLY simplify your queries: `WHERE DAY(datetimefield)='2013-08-23' GROUP BY HOUR(datetimefield)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT visitor_date, count(*) FROM visitors_table WHERE visitor_date = CURDATE() group by visitor_hour`